# How to drill down a XML file with Angular

Tags: xml, angularjs

I need to display health topics from medline. I am using xml2json to translate it but I cannot figure out how to display what i need. I am getting a not defined message but I am not sure why? I created a plunker and I am attaching a photo of what i need displayed. Basically it is just the title and links if available.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6QaxkzZP61Nl62RNqzf?p=preview)

```
Error: topics is not defined
```

code

```
 app.factory('medlineFactory',function($http){
      var factory = [];

      factory.getHealthTopics = function(){
        return $http.get("healthTopics.xml");
      }

        return factory;
    });

    app.controller('healthTopics',function($scope,medlineFactory){

      $scope.healthTopics = [];
      loadHealthTopics();

      function loadHealthTopics(){
        medlineFactory.getHealthTopics().success(function(data){
            allTopics  = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
            console.log(allTopics.health-topics.health-topic);
            $scope.healthTopics =allTopics.health-topics.health-topic;
        });
        }
    });
```

[image: display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can advise you to use **x2js** more info here  https://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Please see working demo here : http://plnkr.co/edit/pob3c28vkC3qR1hXfCv0?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.xml = '';
  $scope.dom = {};


  $http.get('sample.xml').then(function(response) {

    $scope.xml = response.data
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    $scope.dom = x2js.xml_str2json($scope.xml);
    $scope.topics = $scope.dom['health-topics']


  })


});
```

Comment: @texas697 you are right plunker is here http://plnkr.co/edit/pob3c28vkC3qR1hXfCv0?p=preview

Comment: think you posted the same one again :-)

Comment: @texas697 this time here http://plnkr.co/edit/pob3c28vkC3qR1hXfCv0?p=preview showing me topis as JSON

Comment: awesome. one more question, how do I display <descriptor id="D015746">Abdominal Pain</descriptor>   I do not see that in the json

Comment: @texas697 {{topics['health-topic']._title}} http://plnkr.co/edit/pob3c28vkC3qR1hXfCv0?p=preview